# Even with Defer and Addeventlistener, Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript

this code return:

```
ncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

JS code

```
let cartProducts = document.getElementById('products');
if (cartProducts) {
  let lastItem = cartProducts.lastElementChild;
  console.log(lastItem);
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          cartProducts.classList.remove('bg-red');
        } else {
          cartProducts.classList.add('bg-red');
        }
      });
    },
    { threshold: 1 },
  );
  observer.observe(lastItem);
}
```

Comment: console `lastItem`  return `null`

Comment: even when using `addEventListener`, or `defer`, same issue

Comment: `products ` return a list of items from another `fetch` async function